# Show locations of duplicate lines across multiple files

Tags: command-line, bash, sh

I have two files:

```
#a.txt

11
22
33
44
55
11
```

And

```
# b.txt

55 
66 
77 
88 
99 
11
```

I do this command to print duplicate lines across two files: `sort *.txt | uniq -D`
And it outputs:

```
11
11
11
55
55
```

I would like it to output the exact locations; i.e. for line 1 from output it should say where it came from: *line 1, file a.txt* i.e. a kind of diff.

Any ideas how I can do this please?

Comment: I think I got something that might work.  It looks ugly for now, but `grep -n` shows line numbers.  Also, feeding it to `uniq` one more time can reduce the amount of searching.  So, something like `sort *.txt | uniq -D | uniq | while read num; do grep -n $num *.txt; done` might work?

Comment: Thank you so much. This solution works on the example that I gave, but it does not work if a line has spaces. The answer given below has no problem with spaces. God bless!

Comment: No worries.  If you only had the one column here like in your example, `awk '{print $1}'` works too.  `sort *.txt | awk '{print $1}' | uniq -D | uniq | while read num; do grep -n $num *.txt; done`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### TL;DR

You can do something like this:

```
file_expr="*.txt"; sort $file_expr | sed 's/^\s*//; s/\s*$//; /^\s*$/d' | uniq -d | while read dup_line; do grep -Hn "^\s*$dup_line\s*$" $file_expr; done| sort -t: -k3 -k1,2 | awk -F: '{ file=$1; line=$2; $1=$2=""; gsub(/(^[ \t]+)|([ \t]+$)/,"",$0); if (prev != "" && prev != $0) printf ("\n"); printf ("\033[0;33m%s (line %s)\033[0m: %s\n", file, line, $0); prev=$0; }'
```

Result:

```
a.txt (line 3): 11
a.txt (line 8): 11
b.txt (line 8): 11

a.txt (line 7): 55
b.txt (line 3): 55
```

Change the content of the variable `file_expr` to change the files affected

---

### Explanation

I used the `sed` command to **trim** all *trailing* and *leading* whitespaces and **remove empty lines**, making the `uniq -d` get only the lines which are REALLY duplicate...

Then i **loop** over the duplicate lines (printed one for every match) and i `grep` them into the files using the flags `-n` (**print file** and **line**) and `-H` (**always** show the **filename**). The expression `^\s*$dup_line\s*$` into the `grep` make it match the **whole line** (so that for example "qwerty**11**uiop" doesn't match).

As you can see it works both using **file globbing**...

```
file_expr="*.txt"; sort $file_expr | sed 's/^\s*//; s/\s*$//; /^\s*$/d' | uniq -d | while read dup_line; do grep -Hn "^\s*$dup_line\s*$" $file_expr; done
```

Result:

```
a.txt:3:11  
a.txt:8:11  
b.txt:8:11  
a.txt:7:55  
b.txt:3:55
```

... and **literal file names**..

```
file_expr="a.txt b.txt"; sort $file_expr | sed 's/^\s*//; s/\s*$//; /^\s*$/d' | uniq -d | while read dup_line; do grep -Hn "^\s*$dup_line\s*$" $file_expr; done
```

Result:

```
a.txt:3:11
a.txt:8:11
b.txt:8:11
a.txt:7:55
b.txt:3:55
```

---

### Little Tweaks

I then played around a little to make it visually more **comfortable**... Like this:

```
file_expr="a.txt b.txt"; sort $file_expr | sed 's/^\s*//; s/\s*$//; /^\s*$/d' | uniq -d | while read dup_line; do grep -Hn "^\s*$dup_line\s*$" $file_expr; done| sort -t: -k3 -k1,2 | awk -F: '{ file=$1; line=$2; $1=$2=""; gsub(/(^[ \t]+)|([ \t]+$)/,"",$0); if (prev != "" && prev != $0) printf ("\n"); printf ("\033[0;33m%s (line %s)\033[0m: %s\n", file, line, $0); prev=$0; }'
```

Result:

```
a.txt (line 3): 11
a.txt (line 8): 11
b.txt (line 8): 11

a.txt (line 7): 55
b.txt (line 3): 55
```

In this last view everything is more "human" and the duplicates are grouped together first by result and then by file (you can see that the results in `a.txt` are all together), so it's easier to understand..

The file name and the line now are yellow (`\033[0;33m`) to distinguish from the text in the actual line in case of multiline (excuse the word-pun) duplicates

Comment: Thanks Luke this is exactly what I needed!

Comment: @great_man You're welcome.. Glad i helped... ^^

Answer (score 0):

Since in your example the `b.txt` file has spaces in it, you can use `awk` to grab the characters before the space.

Converting from my comments above to an answer here.  You can use `grep -n` to show the line number and the file it came from.  Also add in one more `uniq` command so that when grep loops through the duplicates found it doesn't go through 3 11s and 2 55s.

Quick example:

```
sort *.txt | awk '{print $1}' | uniq -D 
11
11
11
55
55
```

By adding in the second `uniq` the output is only:

```
11
55
```

Now we can add in the `grep` and the `while` loop.  `grep` will show us how many times each one appears and which file they are in.

```
sort *.txt | awk '{print $1}' | uniq -D | uniq | while read num; do grep -n $num *.txt; done
```

Example:

```
$ sort *.txt | awk '{print $1}' | uniq -D | uniq | while read num; do grep -n $num *.txt; done
a.txt:2:11
a.txt:7:11
b.txt:7:11
a.txt:6:55
b.txt:2:55
```